# How to trigger Reality Composer Action when button is active?

Tags: swift, xcode, reality-composer

I'm currently working on an AR app and I want to trigger an action (for example a scene change) only when a button was pressed beforehand. Here's the process I'm trying to build:

1. Object spawns in front of user
2. User taps on button to select a tool
3. User taps on the object and the action sequence from the RC project gets triggered

So far I created a the initial loading of the Scene,

```
guard let anchor = try? Excavation.loadDirtpile() else {
    return
}
```

a variable for the button state

```
var shovelPressed: Bool = false
```

And a function that sets the state

```
@IBAction func shovelButtonPressed(_ sender: Any) {
    shovelPressed = true
}
```

This is my first time working with Swift and Reality Composer so I'm quite confused :D

I hope you can help!